# phpredis extension doesn't work, unable to load 'redis.so'

Tags: redis, php-extension, phpredis

I installed nginx, php, php-fpm, php-pecl-redis by yum.

All of them work but the last one.

When I run `/usr/sbin/php-fpm`, I got this:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/redis.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/redis.so: undefined symbol: igbinary_unserialize in Unknown on line 0

I don't know what `igbnary_unserialize` means and how to fix it.

I checked the `redis.so` file under right path. I add `extension=redis.so` to `php.ini`

PHP version: 5.3.3

PhpRedis version: 2.2.7

Comment: Are you able to get a `php_info()`?

Comment: @BobvanLuijt I can get `phpinfo()`,If you mean that. But I still can not find reids info  that page

Answer (score 34):

I had the same issue. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Running `sudo apt-get install php-igbinary` resolved the issue for me. I have other issues, but that's what solved this one.

Comment: After upgrading from php7.0 to 7.1, redis was not working for me.. was scratching my head and doing all stuff said on diff forums ...finally this worked..Thanks Matt!

Comment: After upgrading to php 7.2 I was having the same issue that fixed it for me. Thank you.

Comment: This should be the answer :)

Comment: Same for me when updating to php7.3 (from 7.0) for an update of Nextcloud (15->16). (Linux Mint Debian Edition).

Comment: Meanwhile, there's no version for php 7.4; 
The following additional packages will be installed:

  php5.6-igbinary php7.0-igbinary php7.1-igbinary php7.2-igbinary php7.3-igbinary php8.0-igbinary

Answer (score 17):

For people who are upgrading their php from 7.0 to 7.4 like me, and not able to get php-redis working. These are the steps I used after following the answers above.

1) remove Redis

```
sudo apt purge php-redis
```

2) Install Igbinary

```
sudo apt-get install php-igbinary
```

3) Install php-redis again

```
sudo apt-get install php-redis
```

I did the steps above because it seems only php7.0 is recognising the php-redis install but not the currently enabled php7.4

I also recommend removing other versions of PHP if you have should your problem continue unsolved.

Comment: Straight up accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably an issue with igbinary, is this installed? (try for example: `cat /etc/php.d/igbinary.ini`).

Here you can find and install [igbinary](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary#how-to-use)

Comment: What is the outcome of `php_info()`?

Comment: is `php_info()` a correct function? I got 500 err after insert that.

Comment: What if you -in terminal- type: `php php_info();`

Comment: ~O~，but i got the same message like in broswer.I'm going to reinstall the environment

Answer (score 2):

Related to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-redis/+bug/1762935

You should remove php-redis from packages:
`apt purge php-redis` , and install it via `pecl install redis`

You should add "extension=redis.so" to php.ini

and remove redis from config.d in your php directory:

```
rm /etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/@20-redis.ini
```

and

```
rm /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/@20-redis.ini
```

restart php fpm and you will see that problem solved

Answer (score 2):

**On  Ubuntu  20 and  PHP 7.4**
I did  this  and it  worked :

```
sudo apt purge php-redis 

sudo apt  intall php-redis  php7.4-redis
```

TEST redis server :

```
$ php --ri redis
or 
$ redis-cli ping
$ redis-cli info stats
```

Answer (score 0):

just resolve the same problem:

php-pecl-redis installed by yum will cause this problem.
so you need to install the php-redis manually. wget the package and phpize - configure - make ....