# "symbol not found in flat namespace '_PHP_MD5Init' " Error encountered in loading redis dynamic library

Tags: php

[image]

Tried upgrading to PHP 8.1.8 and then made changes to php.ini file for "extension_dir" but it's giving me the above error.

I do not understand how to resolve this. can Anyone help me out here?

Comment: you can find solution to solve this error in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994039/phpredis-extension-doesnt-work-unable-to-load-redis-so)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I'm new to PHP and had to figure out understanding the error for quite a longer time than required.

The problem was basically I had uninstalled redis extension (through pecl) and simply installed redis again using brew.

So then, I installed redis extension through pecl using `arch -arm64 sudo pecl install redis` and was good to go.