# PHP 8.1 - Mac M1 - brew - MongoDB error "symbol not found in flat namespace '_u_strFromUTF8_67'"

Tags: php, mongodb, homebrew

I'm facing this error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_u_strFromUTF8_67'), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm on on Mac with Apple Silicon, php 8.1 installed with "brew tap shivammathur/php".
I'm trying to use php with mongodb, installed with "pecl install mongodb".
When I add extension=mongodb.so or extension="mongodb.so" to my php.ini, I receive this error.

I try to follow another post with a similar error, but with no different result.
["symbol not found in flat namespace '_PHP_MD5Init' " Error encountered in loading redis dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205364/symbol-not-found-in-flat-namespace-php-md5init-error-encountered-in-loadin#new-answer?newreg=2a1d8d98c1ac47338bf6ac33a4e85cd2)

The same approach I used to install xdebug and no problem occoured.

Any help?
What I missed?

Just for info, `pecl list` print out:

```
Package Version State
mongodb 1.14.2  stable
```

Other things maybe can be useful:

```
macOs 12.6
php 8.1.11
mongodb 1.14.2
mongocli 1.27.0
```

Xdebug is also installed by pecl and it works, so I guess it must be something wrong with mongodb's package or something

Comment: But do you have `/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so`? If no, either disable extension in php.ini or install that extension

Comment: Yeah, I have it.
And inside php.ini, "extension_dir" directive is set as "/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20210902"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compiled mongodb with `icu4c 67.1` as dependency and brew most likely updated it.

To fix this make sure icu4c is the latest version and compile the MongoDB
extension again.

```
brew update
brew upgrade icu4c
pecl install -f mongodb
```

Alternatively, you can remove the extension installed using pecl and use the homebrew tap I maintain.
https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions

```
pecl uninstall mongodb
```

```
brew tap shivammathur/extensions
brew install shivammathur/extensions/mongodb@8.1
```

Comment: I tried shivammathur tap (if it is yours, great works! ;) ) and it's works like a charm!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There's a typo in the second command. This should be `brew install shivammathur/extensions/mongodb@8.1`